# Regex to find time in a string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract the time from the following strings using regex

```
Free concert at 8 pm over there
Free concert at 8pm over there
Free concert at 8:30 pm over there
Free concert at 8:30pm over there
```

Does anybody know how to do this using Regex in java?

I've tried the following (1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5]0-9?(?i)(am|pm) but I dont think it allows for words before or after.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Given that this is a very simple regex it appears you haven't put any effort into solving the problem yourself.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: I'm very new to regex but I've tried the following (1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)  but it i dont think it allows for words before and after.  and then i'm not sure how to actually extract the time

Comment: This has nothing to do with google app engine.

Comment: i'm running the code on google app engine =)

Comment: @user1152327 OK, please edit your post and include what you've done in the main body, not in a comment.  Then explain why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: Check this thread, you might get your desired results.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19030256/1147352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: `(?i)at (.+?) over`

**Example:**

```
String str = "Free concert at 8 pm over there"
        + "Free concert at 8pm over there"
        + "Free concert at 8:30 pm over there"
        + "Free concert at 8:30pm over there";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)at (.+?) over");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while( m.find() )
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
8 pm
8pm
8:30 pm
8:30pm
```

**Another one (only time, without at / over or any other word):**

```
(?i)[0-9]{1,2}:??[0-9]{0,2}\\s??(?:am|pm)
```

But there you dont need `group(1)` (you can take `group(0)` or simply `group()`)!

**Example:**

```
String str = "Free concert at 8 pm over there"
        + "Free concert at 8pm over there"
        + "Free concert at 8:30 pm over there"
        + "Free concert at 8:30pm over there";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)[0-9]{1,2}:??[0-9]{0,2}\\s??(?:am|pm)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while( m.find() )
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: The _"at ... over"_ stuff is spurious, as it's clear that's just boilerplate that's unlikely to ever occur in a real string.

Comment: 8:30 pm ends up becoming 30 pm here.  how do you correct that?

Comment: Are you shure? Tested it with both and returns 8:30 pm (output as posted)

Comment: @Jim Garrison: But sometimes you have lists where the value is between two words - in such cases you only have to replace them. Don't know where the strings come from, but i only can use informations which are posted.

Comment: @ollo - it does work.  I find that if theres a number earlier in the string in fails: "9 Yrs The Lady 5:30 pm." returns "9 yrs"