# Java Regular Expression Matching for hh:mm:ss in String

Tags: java, regex, time

I am parsing a file and it has time based entries in it. format is like:

```
00:02:10-XYZ:Count=10
00:04:50-LMK:Count=3
```

Here what I want is to extract the time value from string line

I have searched many links and couldn't find out the thing what I want, eventually I have written this code.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?i)[0-9]{1,2}:??[0-9]{0,2}:??[0-9]{0,2})"); //(?i)[0-9]{1,2}:??[0-9]{0,2}:??[0-9]{0,2}  //\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}
    Matcher matcher;
    List<String> listMatches;
```

Below is the loop where I apply logic

```
    for(int x = 0; x < file_content.size(); x++)
    {
            matcher= pattern.matcher(file_content.get(x));
            listMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(matcher.find())
            {
                listMatches.add(matcher.group(1));
                break;
            }
     }
```

I want when "matcher.find()" gives true it returns me [00:02:10] in first iteration and [00:04:50] in 2nd iterations.

Comment: have you considered using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead of writing your own regex?

Comment: No sir, I didn't , Thanks for sharing your value-able code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like an unnecessarily complicated pattern.... why not just (if you are doing line-by-line processing):

```
"^(\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)"
```

If you are doing multi-line processing you will want to use:

```
"(?m)^(\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)"
```

Here's some example code and output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("00:02:10-XYZ:Count=10\n00:04:50-LMK:Count=3");
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.printf("[%s]\n", matcher.group(1));
    }        
}
```

outputs

```
[00:02:10]
[00:04:50]
```

Comment: What about input like `99:99:99`? Your regex matches non-time values :(  p.s. and why group the match? Did you know you can just get group zero?

Answer (score 4):

I did with this way.

```
00:02:10-XYZ:Count=10
00:04:50-LMK:Count=3

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]:([0-5][0-9]|[6][0])");
//File Beginning Time
for(int x = 0; x < file_content.size(); x++)
   {
        matcher= pattern.matcher(file_content.get(x));
        ListMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(matcher.find())
          {
                start_time = matcher.group();
                break;
          }                
    }
//File End Time
for(int x = file_content.size()-1; x > 0 ; x--)
        {
            matcher= pattern.matcher(file_content.get(x));
            listMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                end_time = matcher.group();
                break;
            }                  
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex for this, use a `SimpleDateFormat`. This has two massive advantages

1. The code in `SimpleDateFormat` is tested and robust
2. The `SimpleDateFormat` will validate to ensure that you have real time numbers

This would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String s = "00:02:10-XYZ:Count=10\n"
            + "00:04:50-LMK:Count=3";
    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = sc.nextLine();
        final Date date = dateFormat.parse(line);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
2
10
0
4
50
```

From the [javadoc for `DateFormat.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29):

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.
>   The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

So the `SimpleDateFormat` will parse the `String` until it reads the whole pattern specified then stops.

Comment: seems like it should be `("KK:mm:ss")`

Comment: @Anirudh, you're right - it shouldn't be `hh`, but I think it should be `HH`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm:ss");    
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+:\\d+:\\d+");
Matcher matcher;
List<Date> listMatches = new ArrayList<Date>();
for(int x = 0; x < file_content.size(); x++)
{
    matcher= pattern.matcher(file_content.get(x));
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        Date temp=null;
        try{temp=dateFormat.parse(matcher.group(0));}catch(ParseException p){}
        if(temp!=null)
        listMatches.add(temp);
    }
}
```