# Regex for time in hh:mm am/pm format in java

Tags: java, regex, time-format

I need to make strict validation of input for my project, time in format HH:MM am/pm. So far i've got this RegEx expression:

`(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)`

Above expression working fine but when I pass 09:05 AM its not working and its working when i pass 9:05 AM

Can some one suggest me please how can i solve this problem.

### Code

```
public class SampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputTimeString = "09:05 PM";
        boolean isValidaTim = isValidTime(inputTimeString);
        if (isValidaTim) {
            System.out.println("Valid time string: " + inputTimeString);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid time string: " + inputTimeString);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidTime(String time) {
        String regexPattern = "(1[012]|[1-9]):" + "[0-5][0-9](\\s)" + "?(?i)(am|pm)";
        Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
        if (time == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Matcher m = compiledPattern.matcher(time);
        return m.matches();
    }

}
```

Comment: Must you use a regex?

Comment: No its mandatory to use .I want working code

Comment: So using a regex is required??  Or could you use LocalTime?

Comment: For a match only, you don't need the capturing groups. You have to add an optional zero to match `09` and you can use a character class for the am pm part `(?:1[012]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\\h?(?i)[ap]m` See https://regex101.com/r/0ien3M/1

Comment: Related questions that may answer yours: (1) [Regex for time in hh:mm am/pm format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906033/regex-for-time-in-hhmm-am-pm-format) (2) [Java Regular Expression Matching for hh:mm:ss in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029880/java-regular-expression-matching-for-hhmmss-in-string)

Comment: Regex is overkill here. See the use of *java.time* classes shown in [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64835194/642706)

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

Don’t use a regular expression for this. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("h:mm a")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

public static boolean isValidTime(String time) {
    try {
        LocalTime.parse(time, timeFormatter);
        return true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To try it out:

```
    System.out.println("Is 9:05 am valid? " + isValidTime("9:05 am"));
    System.out.println("Is 09:05 PM valid? " + isValidTime("09:05 PM"));
```

Output:

> ```
> Is 9:05 am valid? true
> Is 09:05 PM valid? true
> ```

If you want to allow single-digit minutes and permit omitting the space, write your pattern like this:

```
        .appendPattern("h:m[ ]a")
```

> ```
> Is 09:10PM valid? true
> Is 09:5 PM valid? true
> ```

For most purposes you should also keep the `LocalTime` object that results from parsing rather than keep your time in a string.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the regex. You start with `1[012]|[1-9]`. So, either 10, or 11, or 12, or a single non-zero digit. Update the second part, and note that 00 is also a valid hour: `1[012]|0?[0-9]` will get the job done. There are many regex tutorials and testers out there.

You then shove a question mark as first char in the final bit for am/pm - whatever is that about? That's making the last digit of minute optional, that seems bizarre; it means `10:5` matches but `10:6` won't. You presumably want to allow spaces in between, so toss a `\\s*` in there too.

Comment: Thanks working now.But if i pass 09:10PM or 09:5 PM it should allow can you suggest please

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this one `(\d|0\d|1[012]):([0-5]\d)\s*(am|pm)`

The hour `(\d|0\d|1[012])` can be a single digit, a zero and a single digit or 10,11,12

The minute `([0-5]\d)` can be a 0 to 5 followed by a second digit