# Regex to extract time (e.g. 7:30pm, 8 pm, 9.05) from string

Tags: regex

I'm working on a Rails application which uses an external feed for some event data and annoyingly they only provide a string with the time in. For example:

> Doors open at 7:30pm, show starts at 9pm

I'm aiming to extract the first time from these strings and put it into a datetime field. The system needs to capture the following kinds of values:

1. 11 am
2. 12pm
3. 1pm
4. 2:15pm
5. 3.30pm
6. 4.45
7. 5:30
8. 06:15
9. 07:30pm
10. 8:30 pm
11. 9.15 pm

But not these ones:

12. 105
13. 2 50
14. 305pm
15. 4 15pm
16. 74pm
17. 840am

I figure the best way to do this is with regex and through some searching (and particularly [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504012/regex-to-find-time-in-a-string)) I've got the following:

`[0-9]{1,2}(:|.)??[0-9]{0,2}\s?(am|pm|AM|PM)`

It partly works but doesn't exclude any of the ones I don't want and seems to only capture the first character of am/pm in 2 and 3.

Is this possible with regex?

Thanks!

Comment: `??`? 0-or-1 of the previous 0-or-1?

Comment: Not sure – I pieced it together from different bits I found so I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Comment: @MarcB It's actually a non-greedy 0-or-1. It will match the previous item if it exists, but it won't be captured unless necessary. In practice, I've never found an actual use for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
^[01]?[0-9]([:.][0-9]{2})?(\s?[ap]m)?$
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%5B01%5D?%5B0-9%5D%28%5B%3a.%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29?%28%5Cs?%5Bap%5Dm%29?%24&input=11%20am%0A12pm%0A1pm%0A2:15pm%0A3.30pm%0A4.45%0A5:30%0A06:15%0A07:30pm%0A8:30%20pm%0A9.15%20pm%0A%0A105%0A2%2050%0A305pm%0A4%2015pm%0A74pm%0A840am)

Note that this will not handle 24-hour time, and it's not that specific about 12-hour time—i.e. it would match `19pm`.

If you want to be more specific, you might try:

```
^((0?[0-9]|1[012])([:.][0-9]{2})?(\s?[ap]m)|([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])([:.][0-9]{2})?)$
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%28%280?%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D%29%28%5B%3a.%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29?%28%5Cs?%5Bap%5Dm%29%7C%28%5B01%5D?%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-3%5D%29%28%5B%3a.%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29?%29%24&input=11%20am%0A12pm%0A1pm%0A2:15pm%0A3.30pm%0A4.45%0A5:30%0A06:15%0A07:30pm%0A8:30%20pm%0A9.15%20pm%0A%0A105%0A2%2050%0A305pm%0A4%2015pm%0A74pm%0A840am)

Or to try to match it as part of a larger portion of text, you might use something like this:

```
\b((0?[1-9]|1[012])([:.][0-5][0-9])?(\s?[ap]m)|([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])([:.][0-5][0-9]))\b
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5Cb%28%280?%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D%29%28%5B%3a.%5D%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D%29?%28%5Cs?%5Bap%5Dm%29%7C%28%5B01%5D?%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-3%5D%29%28%5B%3a.%5D%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D%29%29%5Cb&input=Lorem%20ipsum%2011%20am%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%2012pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%201pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%202:15pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%203.30pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%204.45%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%205:30%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%2006:15%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%2007:30pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%208:30%20pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%209.15%20pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0A%0ALorem%20ipsum%20105%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%202%2050%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%20305pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%204%2015pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%2074pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%20840am%20lorem%20ipsum)

Comment: You probably don't want the anchors, since it appears that the OP is trying to pull times out of a larger string.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly but it needs to pull it out of the string [like this](http://bit.ly/1cTQHJ2).

Answer (score 8):

```
\b((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?!\d| (?![ap]))[:.]?(?:(?:[0-5][0-9]))?(?:\s?[ap]m)?)\b
```

It doesn't support 24-hour format but it enforces valid times. Add a case insensitive flag to your regex engine, whatever language it may be, or wrap the regex with `(i: )` if it is supported.

[Demo with your sample](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5Cb%28%28%3F%3A0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-2%5D%29%28%3F!%5Cd%7C%20%28%3F!%5Bap%5D%29%29%5B%3A.%5D%3F%28%28%3F%3A%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D%29%29%3F%28%3F%3A%5Cs%3F%5Bap%5Dm%29%3F%29%5Cb&input=Lorem%20ipsum%2011%20am%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%2012pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%201pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%202%3A15pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%203.30pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%204.45%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%205%3A30%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%2006%3A15%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%2007%3A30pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%208%3A30%20pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%209.15%20pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0A%0ALorem%20ipsum%20105%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%202%2050%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%20305pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%204%2015pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%2074pm%20lorem%20ipsum%0ALorem%20ipsum%20840am%20lorem%20ipsum)

Regex:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0?                       '0' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-2]                    any character of: '0' to '2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [ap]                     any character of: 'a', 'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [:.]?                    any character of: ':', '.' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-5]                    any character of: '0' to '5'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (optional (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [ap]                     any character of: 'a', 'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      m                        'm'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Comment: Looks pretty close to what I had. +1 for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I have nested negative look-aheads, I would think that your answer performs better without those!

Comment: Your cheatsheet is very helpful. Thanks